# How to create model and parse response from server in json format?

Tags: json, dart

I have response from server in JSON format. It looks like this:

```
{
"api_data": {   
"users": [
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Jhon",
        "age": 34,
        "status": {
            "text": "Hello, World!"
        },
        "photos": {
            "avatar": "https://",
            "favColors": {
                "colors": [
                    "#FFFFFF",
                    "#09927F"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "Helena",
        "age": 20,
        "status": {
            "text": "Always happy"
        },
        "photos": {
            "avatar": "https://",
            "favColors": {
                "colors": [
                    "#FFFFFF",
                    "#000000"
                ]
            }
        }
        
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "Barbara",
        "age": 41,
        "status": {
            "text": "I'm here now"
        },
        "photos": {
            "avatar": "https://",
            "favColors": {
                "colors": [
                    "#344A13",
                    "#000000"
                ]
            }
        }
        
    }
]
}
```

But I don't understand how to create a model in Dart (a class) and parse this nested json object. Should I do it manually or I can use json_annotation and json_serializable?

Comment: You posted incorrect json, there is missing curly bracket before "api data".

It's up to you. It depends are you more familiar with manually or this packages. But you can easily paste this json on site like this -> https://app.quicktype.io/ 
and get Dart objects

Comment: @ivanX yes, that's my mistake. thanks for the link!